# Cloud Firestore: How to get a specific value from all random generated documents

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, annotations

Is there a way I can get hold of a specific value of all documents created in Firestore?

This is how my Firestore is structured:

[firebase_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04sXv.png)

I want to get hold of the "Latitude" and "Longitude" datas so I can have annotations on my `mapView`. So for each "post" there is going to be an annotation.

The code provided in the Firebase documentation (I'm also sharing below) seems not to work for me since I only can get the data of all of the elements inside **one specific** path.

```
let docRef = db.collection("cities").document("SF")

docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
    if let document = document, document.exists {
        let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
        print("Document data: \(dataDescription)")
    } else {
        print("Document does not exist")
    }
}
```

The problem is that even if I type in that specific path, then how am I able to get the "Latitude" and "Longitude" values of other paths? Is there something else that I am missing?

I hope this makes sense. I am new to programming and tried my best to explain. I've been struggling with this for two days now.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to retrieve thoso values from the document, try something like this:

```
let docRef = db.collection("cities").document("SF")
docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
   if let document = document, document.exists {
    let data = document.data()
    let latitude = data["latitude"] as? String, 
    let longitude =  data["longitude"] as? String{
    print("latitude = \(latitude)")
    print("longitude = \(longitude)")
} else {
    print("Document does not exist")
}
```

You can also create a specific Struct for a cleaner implementation:

```
let coordenates = coordenate(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
print("coordenates: \(coordenates)")
```

Comment: Hello Alexis, this code doesn't seem to work since I am getting these errors: 
"Use of unresolved identifier 'data'" and "Use of unresolved identifier 'document'"

Comment: Pastet it's contyents in your original code for better context :)